# JQuery serialize form on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization

I have a simple form that i want to submit to JQuery. My following code almost works, but is behaving funny. I have two buttons, a submit(serialize) and a cancel(do nothing). both point to the same javascript function, but when submit is pressed a alert box pops up. On a fresh page load clicking submit will do nothing, but if you click it one more time, it will show the alert box, but twice. If you click it again, it will pop up 3 times and so on and so on. The cancel button, if it is pressed does nothing, however it also adds to the number of times the alert box pops up next time you click submit. I looked at alot of examples, and as far as I can tell, I am doing this correctly

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="test" action="">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" /><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse" /><br>
  </form>

  <button id="tbutton" onclick="test()">Serialize</button>
  <button id="fbutton" onclick="test()">do nothing</button>

</body>
```

My Function:

```
function test() {
  $("#tbutton").click(function(){
    alert($('#test').serialize());
  });
}
```

I would like to get the form info into the AJAX function as it is used elsewhere in my project, and form data is not always used.

```
function get_node_data(u_id) {
var xmlhttp;
var ser_new_area = "";

    $("#move").click(function(){
        alert($('#move_node').serialize());
        var ser_new_area = $('#move_node').serialize();
    });

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("data_main").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "AJAX_node_overview.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("u_id=" + u_id + "&" + ser_new_area);
}
```

Comment: We didn't have your ajax.js code. Can you post your code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)? More easy to find the problem.

Comment: Why you have two bindings to the same button? You should remove the onclick attribute and use the $(selector).click() binding

Comment: Everytime you call your function test() you are binding a new click event to your button. You have to bind the event on page load only.

Comment: ok i am not familliar with $(selector).click(), I will look into it. New to Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With @mart's and others help I came up with this:

Bind button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tbutton").click(function(){
   test($('#test').serialize());
  });
 });
```

function:

```
function test(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is you are calling test function when you click the Serialize button and in that function you are binding the event click of the button to a function.

Try changing this:

```
$(document).ready(
   $("#tbutton").click(function(){
       alert($('#test').serialize());
  }); 
)
```

And in your html:

```
<button id="tbutton">Serialize</button>
<button id="fbutton">do nothing</button>
```

Comment: I need to do that inside a function, as clicking cancel would go back to the previous page. I will edit my post.

Comment: Thanks this helped me alot. I need to bind the click on page load, then call the function from that

Comment: I am having trouble with the buttons working inside AJAX loaded content. Any tips on this? they work fine on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <form id="test" action="">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" /><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse" /><br>
  </form>

  <button id="tbutton">Serialize</button>
  <button id="fbutton">do nothing</button>

</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 $(function() {
     $("#tbutton").click(function(){
         alert($('#test').serialize());
     });
 });
```